# Error when i try to recieve my form from my html and put it in my php

Tags: php, html, forms

can anyone explain where I am going wrong with this?
Here's the form, found on a webpage named genericwebpage.html

```
<form name = "quoted" form action = "genericwebpage.php" method="get">
<input id = "poster" type="text" name="poster" placeholder = "Credited Individual.">     <br>
<textarea class = "actual-quote" name = "actual-quote"placeholder = "Write the quote here!"></textarea><br><br>
<input id = "submit1" type="submit">
</form>
```

and heres the php, found on genericwebpage.php

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="submissions">
<div class="logo-logo"><h2>Generic.</h2></div>
<div class="top-submit"><?php echo $_GET['actual-quote']?></div>
<div class="poster"><?php echo $_GET['poster']?></div>
</div>
```

can someone guide me in the right direction on fixing this, i've seen alot of people use isset but I don't know if that will work in this case?

Comment: i still get the undefined index, do i have to directly link it or something?

Comment: The above code works fine on my system. Are you sure, its not something else that you're missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `isset()` or `empty()` to check value is seted or not empty to avoid php notices Also use space between every attr(placeholder/name) in form fields

```
<form name = "quoted" form action = "genericwebpage.php" method="get">
<input id = "poster" type="text" name="poster" placeholder = "Credited Individual.">     <br>
<textarea class = "actual-quote" name = "actual-quote" placeholder = "Write the quote here!"></textarea><br><br>
<input id = "submit1" type="submit">
</form>
```

php

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="submissions">
<div class="logo-logo"><h2>Generic.</h2></div>
<div class="top-submit"><?php echo (!empty($_GET['actual-quote']) ? $_GET['actual-quote'] : '');?></div>
<div class="poster"><?php echo (!empty($_GET['poster']) ? $_GET['poster'] :'');?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put atleast one space between name and placeholder of textarea.

Answer (score 1):

PHP shows that "actual-quote" isn't being received. This is because your missing a space after the namefield. Copy and paste it, here is the correct one:

```
<form name = "quoted" form action = "genericwebpage.php" method="get">
<input id = "poster" type="text" name="poster" placeholder = "Credited Individual.">     <br>
<textarea class = "actual-quote" name = "actual-quote" placeholder = "Write the quote here!"></textarea><br><br>
<input id = "submit1" type="submit">
</form>
```